# What exactly is the legendary treasure One Piece ? Have there been any references to its nature: such as jewels, wishes, devil fruits etc.?

Tags: one-piece

I am confused what exactly is the treasure One Piece. Is it some sort of jewels, blessings, legendary Devil Fruits or something like that? Or is it really just ONE PIECE OF SOMETHING?

Comment: There's no point in asking for something which will be covered later in the story.

Comment: The answer to this question has been deliberately not disclosed by the author. Come back in 5 years and you might have it.

Answer (score 6):

Obviously, the nature of the treasure is so far unknown. The only actual information based on some quote attributed to Oda himself is that it should **NOT** be something like "friendship" or "the journey".

> Oda(2019): One Piece is not a *bond of Straw Hats*. I hate that kind of thing. When I was a kid, I was not happy with the ending of The Wizard of Oz, that the adventure is itself a treasure. That story was unacceptable. Luffy has a great journey, so give him a proper treasure.

source: https://twitter.com/sandman_AP/status/1653374993328394246

That said, I don't trust much of that other being a red herring since **imho** Oda shoved to love quite a bit throwing misleading elements at the fans. For example, nothing in the above message implies that it is a) anything actually valuable, b) anything that can be moved from the island, c) in a way anything physical (for example, would "the Dawn and freedom from the lies of the Dragons" be considered a treasure? Remember that the Straw Hats consider things like tangerines, an old flag, a sword and a promise to a dead girl, an straw hat, some burnt plans etc as treasures), d) anything that is STILL there (Roger said he was not the one Joy Boy was waiting for. But some think Joy Boy left **that** fruit there, and the reason Roger didn't took it was his terminal illness. This would also mean that Shanks was fully aware of what that fruit really was, and attacked the ship carrying it on purpose, not just as a random coincidence) .

It is also worth noticing that when Roger reached Laugh Tale, something was already there. And that is the reason the name Laugh Tale was chosen in the first place.

[image: Scan of the "He laughed" scene after Roger reached Laugh Tale]

Yet, "One Piece" is the name give to what people believe to be Roger's treasure. Something that **they** believe was left there.

[image: Origin of the One Piece name]

Notice Roger's reaction: "And they have no idea".
"No idea" about what? About the fact that he didn't leave anything there and the only treasure is what Joy Boy already left? About the fact that the treasure has no monetary value at all, being instead something like "knowledge" or "a way to bring on the Dawn"? The real throne to the world and the proof the Dragons are in fact usurpers from another land?

Consider this:
Buggy was with Roger's crew. Conveniently, he had some "illness" that prevented him to go on Laugh Tale.

[image: Buggy getting ill before Roger's crew departs to Laugh Tale]

The nature of this illness hasn't been further elaborated (some fan translations of the page call it "Can't Go to this Island", the same name Usopp uses as an excuse multiple times, but that is not correct). Anyway, it seems like a way to distract the watcher from a specific question:  "considering that Buggy is depicted as someone who loves treasures why did he never try to find a way to get the One Piece for himself if it was so precious and he already knew its location? Why he didn't ask Shank to bring back even a single coin? Why aiming for a different treasure altogether if he knew what Roger left there?"

Also... Why the World Government should be afraid about something finding a very large sum of money? Whitebeard seemed to imply that finding the One Piece would trigger some world-level crisis and Sengoku reaction seems to confirm that. What do they really fear? Some large treasure called One Piece or something else left there before? Is the One Piece a treasure at all?
It is pretty evident Roger planted the idea of a treasure as a deliberate way to get people trying to reach that same final line so that they would find something else there, but it is not clear if there is an actual treasure too or just that "something else". He just seemed to want for someone else to reach that point in the journey.

And perhaps, do something there he couldn't or didn't want to do at the time.

[image: Rayleigh implying the Straw Hats may find a different answer on the last island]

It is also worth noticing that there have been some hints about Luffy destroying Fish-Man island. The world of One Piece is spit in 4 quadrants so right now it is basically Four Pieces. Something huge happened in the past, and the Throne is found on the Red Line, and Fish-Man island is somewhere under that.
Was the answer under our nose all along? Is "One Piece" nothing else that the world once again awakened and restored to the one single land it once was? Is that why  the "All Blue" is so rarely mentioned in the plot and the reason no one could find it? Because it no longer exist?

PS: At least we should be pretty confident it is not a giant pearl...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The One Piece is the end goal of the story. Since you are asking about that, I assume you have no problem with any and all spoilers.

[image: Luffy angry]
[image: Luffy irate]

Though it is impossible to say with any certainty what the One Piece is at this point in the story, we are far from clueless about what is waiting on Laugh Tale. In the first place, this island is connected heavily to the Poneglyphs. Finding the path to Laugh Tale requires deciphering the four Red Poneglyphs. It is highly likely that the Poneglyph detailing the Void Century will be there, but whether or not this itself is the One Piece, or part of the One Piece, is unknown.

The One Piece has been implied to be something that will turn the world upside down. At times, some characters' dialogue has even implied that the One Piece might be one of the Ancient Weapons, or something related to the ancient weapons. Given the Poneglyphs relation to these weapons, this is not a far-fetched assumption. However, I suspect this might not actually be the case even though some characters seem convinced of this, and just the history from the Void Century could be enough to turn the world upside down, so a weapon is not necessary.

Gold Roger's final words also offer a clue:

> "You want my treasure? You can have it! I left everything I gathered together in one place. Now you just have to find it."

This implies it was something he gathered together, rather than something he found on the island. It could be that the One Piece is an amalgamation of some treasure Roger found on his journey, as well as some things he found on Laugh Tale.

There are some more clues. Whitebeard said to Blackbeard that Blackbeard wasn't the one Roger was waiting for. And in the movie *One Piece: Stampede*, Roger himself gets angry about the Eternal Log Pose to Laugh Tale being made, and says that the treasure is beyond anyone who would use such a thing.

I haven't actually gotten to this part of the story myself, so I can't say much, but I've heard the One Piece has something to do with Joy Boy.

The name Laugh Tale may also be an important hint as to what the One Piece is, since Gold Roger named the island that in response to what he found there.

What is very clear though, is that there is an expectation that whoever gets the One Piece will be the person who ends the current era and starts a new one.